# XSL Transformation giving NaN for integers having "-" in between

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following xml code and I have applied transformation on it to get my data upto 5 decimal points. But I dont want to apply transformation for the data which has "-" in between. See column1.

```
<Column1>1718-001</Column1>
<Column2>2013</Column2>
<Column3>KK</Column3>
<Column4>42000</Column4>
```

This is the xslt which I have applied.

```
 <xsl:template match = "*[translate(.,'-0123456789.******', '') = ''][not(*)]            

   [translate(.,'-0123456789.*****', '') = '']">

    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="format-number(number(.), '0.00000')"/>

    </xsl:copy>
```

This is the result which I got . But I dont want to apply xslt on the data which has "-"
 in between.(I don want that NaN )

```
 <Row>
 <Column1>NaN</Column1>
 <Column2>2013.00000</Column2>
 <Column3>KK</Column3>
 <Column4>42000.00000</Column4>
 </Row>
```

Comment: @Micheal Kay Please Help me.

Comment: Where do you want to allow the `-` character? Probably only as `substring(., 1, 1)`, no?

Comment: I just dont want to apply it on the data which will be something like 1718-001, which you can see in column1. I want to retain it as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this do what you need:

```
<xsl:template match = "*[not(*) and number() = number()]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="format-number(., '0.00000')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

It will match only leaf elements whose string value can be successfully converted to a number.